# Singular VS Plural Is/are

Tags: singular-vs-plural, plural-forms, singular

Which one is correct:

> Flowers is a good present.

Or

> Flowers are a good present.

Or

> The best present for me is flowers.

Or

> The best present for me are flowers.

Comment: There are numerous duplicates as seen in the 'Related' panel on the right, and [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=english+language+learners+stack+exchange+singular+plural+is%2Fare).

Comment: "Flower**s** **are** a good present / The best **present** **is** flowers". In each of those examples the verb matches the subject.

Comment: "Flowers is" does not work because it's a plural, but it can be made to work if you combine the flowers into one collective noun.  A bouquet of flowers is a good present.

Comment: It depends entirely on context. It can be considered a collective noun even if you don't add any words to it. Consider a different noun. *"What **is** a good present?" "M&M's [**is** a good present]."* Even though *M&M's* *is* plural (forget about the apostrophe in the proper name), it can still take a singular verb. You can replace *M&M's* with *flowers* and still use the same syntax. If both versions sound wrong, then just rephrase the sentence.

Comment: Not true. Plural M&M's requires a plural verb, unless it is construed as the singular noun phrase M&M's chocolate. Generally, the verb matches the subject. "Flowers" is construed as a number of stems and thus plural, so the verb should also be the plural "are". Note that if we reverse the order, i.e. "A nice present is flowers", the verb becomes singular to match the singular subject. With measure expressions, things are different, c.f. "Ten days is a long time to be on your own" / "Twenty pounds is to much to pay".